# How can we avoid writing in the hosts file

Tags: delphi, tchromium

We have a website.  For it to run, we need to add an entry in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file, like this:

```
172.16.1.100 games.la.com
```

We don't want to write in the `hosts` file.  Also, the ip and domain is confidential.  Is this doable?  If not, what are some other solutions/alternatives to this problem?

Comment: So this client-side or server-side? Why do you need the modify the `hosts` file to make this work? What's wrong with letting DNS resolve `games.la.com` to the proper IP? Does `games.la.com` even have proper DNS entries?

Comment: client side.. the website is local only..

Comment: Why not just use the private address? You need to provide more detail in your question as to what you want to achieve (other than avoiding modifying hosts)

Comment: If the website is local, but relies on accessing a specific domain, there is nothing else you can do. The whole point of the `hosts` file is to provide domain lookups without involving DNS. Otherwise, redesign the website to access everything it needs relative to where it is running from, and then access it using the server's local IP (if a local server is involved) or just open the local HTML file directly.

Comment: We have server that has no internet connection, only local connection. We hosted the website there. For users to access the site, we edit the hosts file to make it work. Even if I know "DNS Entries"(which I don't), they will not use it. They want the IP and domain hard-coded in program.. Is that even possible in the first place?

Comment: Of course you can hard-code the IP address. If anything, that's the preferred method, **IF** that IP is not expected to change. If you write to the Hosts file, I assume it's a one-time setup. That makes me assume you have an IP which is already static. Why not ditch the host name all-together and just provide the IP?

Comment: A website running on a local web server should not rely on a domain. If your website needs this, it is not designed correctly. That is where you should focus your efforts. You DO NOT need a domain to access a local web server. A local website can access local resources without using a domain.

Comment: A confidential IP?